# Error while building project Unreal Engine 4 - fatal error C1083 (SharedPCH.Core.h.pch)

Tags: build, packaging, unreal-engine4, build-error

I created my project on Unreal Engine 4.19, then decided to switch to Unreal Engine 4.21. I worked on the project for many weeks, decided to build it, but I get this error - c1083.

I think the problem is the lack of file SharedPCH.Core.h.pch(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fIW9y5zuBa7pOtU-tuGbzvS5FDcUE474). I have this file in the project folder but with a different extension, if you delete "response", the error still remains.

I did a great job, now I just can not compile my project.
Please help!

I tried to delete Intermediate, Binaries, Saved folders.
I tried to restore Visual Studio 2017, Unreal Engine 4.21.
I tried to use Unreal Engine older or newer.
I tried to remove a lot of plugins.
I tried to cook content.

I use blueprints.

Log file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O2m84M-oF3WBEkppMp2GxOpLtOCPYFNc

Unreal Engine screenshots:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oc2Z4-XJnabtzl_3JGwfA5Xe8LmF_oS7
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DjSJaIxpK7CgQ9_R5VaG2Zvupqx8kMNn

Comment: Have you tried `Generate Visual Studio project files`?

Comment: Thank you for responding, but it did not help me.